# Using generics in C# interfaces

Tags: c#

In my C# app, I have an interface that looks like:

```
public interface IObject
{
  Task<T> GetById<T>(int id);
                
  Task<T> GetAll<T>();      
}
```

I then have a class that implements this interface:

```
public class MyClass : IObject
{
  public async Task<MyClass> GetById(int id)
  {
    return null;
  }

  public async Task<List<MyClass> GetAll()
  {
    var results = new List<MyClass>();
    return results;
  }
}
```

On build, I get the following error:

> MyClass does not implement interface member 'IObject.GetById(int)
>
> MyClass does not implement interface member 'IObject.GetAll(int)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define your T parameter on IObject rather than each individual method.

Comment: But he is changing the T type in GetAll.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move `T` to the interface, and it looks like you need `GetAll` to return a `List<T>`:

```
public interface IObject<T>
{
  Task<T> GetById(int id);

  Task<List<T>> GetAll();      
}

public class MyClass : IObject<MyClass>
{
  public async Task<MyClass> GetById(int id)
  {
    return null;
  }

  public async Task<List<MyClass>> GetAll()
  {
    var results = new List<MyClass>();
    return results;
  }
}
```